# Powershell script Export-CSV cutoff characters in a string of a .TXT files with Comma

Tags: string, powershell, split, delimiter, export-csv

```
1 .. $Count | ForEach-Object { 
    $i = $_.ToString($Length)

    $Offset = $BatchSize * ($_ - 1)
    $outputFile = $ParentDirectory + "\" + $strBaseName + "-" + $i + $strExtension
    If($_ -eq 1) {
        $objFile | Select-Object  -First $BatchSize | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8  
    } Else {
       $objFile | Select-Object -First $BatchSize -Skip $Offset | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 
    }

  }
```

I have a .txt with a comma on row 3 below. My code is stripping anything after the comma as seen below. how do I fix it? My file is pipe delimited.

### Original file contains

```
|Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|
|320|A1| |0900|
|320|A2|This, comma is needed|0900|
|320|A3| |0700|
|320|A4|f2|0900|
|320|A5| |0700|
|320|L2|c6|0900|
```

After splitting into 2 files -notice the missing text after "this,"

file1

```
|Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|
|320|A1| |0900|
|320|A2|This, 
|320|A3| |0700|
```

file2

```
|Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|
|320|A4|f2|0900|
|320|A5| |0700|
|320|L2|c6|0900|
```

Please advise. Thanks

I tried to use delimiter and replace commands. Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you imported your delimited file into `$objFile`, you forgot to pass 
`-Delimiter '|'` to the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) call, which would not interpret your `|`-separated file properly, given that `Import-Csv` - as well as [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) - default to `,` as the separator.

Thus, the solution is to use  `-Delimiter '|'` in *both* your `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` calls.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem with omitting `-Delimiter '|'`, using the in-memory CSV processing cmdlets, [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv):

```
@'
Field1|Field2
Value1|Value2, and more
'@ | 
  ConvertFrom-Csv | 
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output (note the missing `, and more` part, and how the output lines *as a whole* are double-quoted):

```
"Field1|Field2"
"Value1|Value2"
```

- Since header row `Field1|Field2` contains no `,` it became a *single* property in the resulting objects, literally named `Field1|Field2`.
- Since the data row happened to contain `,` it was parsed as *two* fields, and since there is only *one* column, the extra field was simply *discarded*.